# Generating a table with two entries for each i

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

Disclaimer: I'm not a mathematica expert, I have some programming experience but am still learning how to work mathematica. Also, some of the code from the first block here is not my own, copied/adapted from Wolfram Demonstrations project.

What I am trying to do is generate a table of points. I have a list which I am generating like this:

```
width = 4;
tuple = Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, width];
pts2 = N[Rescale[
  FromDigits[#, 3] & /@ 
   CellularAutomaton[{1, 3, 1/2}, #, width], {0, 
   3^width - 1}]] & /@ tuple;
```

Now, what I want to do is have a table which has 3^width entries, each of which is a list of 2d points. For example, here is how I am currently creating the table:

```
curvPts = Table[{pts2[[i, j]], -j}, {i, 1, 3^width}, {j, 1, width}]
```

And my first entry in the table, as expected, looks like:

```
{{0., -1}, {0.5, -2}, {0., -3}, {0.5, -4}}
```

However, what I am trying to do is get each entry to be something like:

```
{{0., 0}, {0., -1}, {0.5, -1}, {0.5, -2}, {0, -2}, {0., -3},{0.5, -3}, {0.5, -4},, {0.5, -4}}
```

Basically for each *i* in the table, I want there to be 2 *j* entries, one for *j* and one for *j-1*. That way the bezier splines I'm using this to generate will have the curvature I want them to. When I put something like

```
Table[{{pts2[[i, j]], -j}, {pts2[[i, j]], -(j-1)}}, {i, 1, 3^width}, {j, 1, width}]
```

The BezierSpline can't read it because the points are nested in pairs.

Any ideas for how to achieve what I'm aiming for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me to be a situation where [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html) can usefully be applied.

Given `pts2` as generated in the question, first get rid of the unwanted last element.

```
pts = Take[#, width] & /@ pts2;
```

Then either of the following

```
tbl = Join @@@ MapIndexed[With[{j = -#2[[2]]}, {{#1, j + 1}, {#1, j}}] &, pts, {2}];

tbl = 
  ReleaseHold @ MapIndexed[With[{j = -#2[[2]]}, Hold[{#1, j + 1}, {#1, j}]] &, pts, {2}];
```

gives

```
Short[tbl, 4]
```

> ```
> {{{0., 0}, {0., -1}, {0.5, -1}, {0.5, -2}, {0., -2}, {0., -3}, {0.5, -3}, {0.5, -4}}, 
>  <<79>>, 
>  {{1., 0}, {1., -1}, {0., -1}, {0., -2}, {0.5, -2}, {0.5, -3}, {0., -3}, {0., -4}}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) to remove the nesting of pairs:

```
width = 4;

t = Join @@@ Table[{{pts2[[i, j]], -(j-1)}, {pts2[[i, j]], -(j)}}, 
  {i, 1, 3^width}, {j, 1, width}];

Graphics[{Hue @ RandomReal[], BezierCurve @ #} & /@ t, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]